# Product details by using contact id

Tags: php

I have a contact table in this table there are two fields contactId and AccountId.
Contact Table->ContactId ,AccountId(Fields of contact table).

I have a product table. In this table i have AccountId and the product details fields.

Product Table->AccountId ,ProductId,ProductName(Fields Of the product table).

Now the things is, i am getting the ContactId.Based on this ContactId I have to get the product details from product tables.

Or in another words i have to perorm the inner join as below

select Contact.ContactId,Product.ProductName
from Contact
Inner join Account on Contact.AccountId=Account.Id
Inner join Product on Account.Id=Product.AccountId
where Contact.ContactId='xyz';

Comment: Can you elaborate your question ? How are product and contact related in your scenario ?

Comment: Contacts are not related to Products by default. Is this some sort of custom relationship you have? In order to access them in the same query, there would need to be a relationship established.

Comment: I have a contact id and account id in my contact table and in product table i have account id but on the front end i am getting the contact id and i want to fetch the product details from this?